# Mule ESB: How to handle multiple Input Queue (WMQ) in a flow - Mule ESB

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mq, mule-el

Please help me in this issue. Initially i have single WMQ (Inbound) connect to Java Transformer, after doing all the transformation, finally message  has been put it in to the file. It is working fine. Later client changed the requirement with Multiple input queues has to connect with Java Transformer( but the transformation logics are same).

I'm searching options in WMQ properties to mention mutiple queue name. Not able find the solution. Though of using JMS not sure is that the current option. Because already i have used WMQ it was working fine.

Please let me know, Is there any ways can we handle multiple input queue (WMQ) connect to its next message Processor. Kindly guide me. Find my Working configuration xml below with single queue.

```
           <wmq:connector name="WMQ" hostName="localhost" port="2025"          queueManager="XXX" channel="XXXX" validateConnections="true" doc:name="WMQ"/>
<flow name="Flow1" doc:name="Flow1">
    <wmq:inbound-endpoint queue="INPUT" connector-ref="WMQ" doc:name="WMQ">
        <wmq:transaction action="NONE"/>
    </wmq:inbound-endpoint>
    <custom-transformer class="purchaseOrgin.Controller" doc:name="Java"/>
    <logger message="****Incoming Payload:#[payload]***" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\Star\Desktop\mule\In" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
</flow>
```

Thanks in advance. I have my deployment date nearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `composite-source` to have multiple inbound endpoints in a flow:

```
<flow ...>
  <composite-source>
     <wmq:inbound-endpoint queue="INPUT" ... />
     <wmq:inbound-endpoint queue="INPUT2" ... />
     ...
  </composite-source>
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks @David. It really worked :). Problem solved. Thanks again for the quick response.